# Setting the page number with a default

Tags: php, array, pagination

Consider this code segment:

```
if (empty($_GET)) {
    $page_number = 1;
} else {
    $page_number = $_GET["page_number"];
}
```

I wonder if there is a better, more succinct way to express that idea. I thought about using a ternary operator, but the improvement over the original is not substantial:

```
$page_number = empty($_GET) ? 1 : $_GET["page_number"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EBrown has a good [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/156267/21444) already, where he shows which steps has to be taken to make sure the page number is set correctly. He also comes up with a handy function. Let me show you another approach, using build-in functionality in PHP to handle the given problem.

---

**Filter the input**

Make use of PHPs [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php):

```
$page_number = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page_number', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

It uses a predefined [validation filter](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) called `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`, that …

> … validates value as integer, optionally from the specified range, and converts to int on success.

So `$page_number` will be of type `int` and not `string` in case of success. If the filter fails, `$page_name` will be `null|false`:

> Value of the requested variable on success, **FALSE** if the filter fails, or **NULL** if the variable_name variable is not set. If the flag **FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE** is used, it returns **FALSE** if the variable is not set and **NULL** if the filter fails.

---

**Should I always default to 1?**

Like in your question, if `$page_number` is not set at all, you should set it to `1`. Using `filter_input` as described before you can test this case like:

```
if (null === $page_number) {
    $page_number = 1;
}
```

But there are more cases to be handled like:

- invalid values, like `-1|0|1000000`<sup>1</sup>
- other non-integer values, like `hello-world|a4fe|1.2`

I recommend to not to default to `1` in any of these cases, but to show a `404` error page instead.

To make sure the integer value of `$page_number` will produce a valid page, you can take it one step further and set a range for the filter. The complete example would look like

```
$page_number = filter_input(
    INPUT_GET,
    'page_number',
    FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    ['options' => ['min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 104]]
);

if (false === $page_number) {
    // show 404 page
}

if (null === $page_number) {
    $page_number = 1;
}
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Unless you have `1000000` or more pages of course.</sup>

Comment: This is just what the doctor ordered. I did not know such a function exist.

Answer (score 6):

You have a surprise bug: what happens when I do `page.php?Name=EBrown`? Well `$_GET` is not empty but your `page_number` sure isn't set.

That said, you should be doing something like the following:

```
$page_number = 1;

if (isset($_GET["page_number"})) {
    $page_number = $_GET["page_number"];
}
```

or

```
$page_number = $_GET["page_number"];

if (!isset($page_number)) {
    $page_number = 1;
}
```

The first defaults and then checks for the parameter, the second checks if it's set then defaults. Take your pick.

But those still don't handle invalid (non-numeric) input, so we can do that as well:

```
$page_number = $_GET["page_number"];

if (isset($page_number) === FALSE || is_numeric($page_number) === FALSE) {
    $page_number = 1;
}
```

Now we *safely* default to `1` when `page_number` is not set, or when it's not numeric.

Of course, we still have *another* bug: what happens if `page_number` is `1.12`? That's *probably* unintended. So, we'll check for that *as well*:

```
$page_number = $_GET["page_number"];

if (isset($page_number) === FALSE || strpos($page_number, '.') !== FALSE || is_numeric($page_number) === FALSE) {
    $page_number = 1;
}
```

And finally we'd extract that to a method:

```
function defaultInt($intValue, $default) {
    if (isset($intValue) === FALSE
        || strpos($intValue, '.') !== FALSE
        || is_numeric($intValue) === FALSE) {
        return $default;
    }

    return $intValue;
}

$page_number = defaultInt($_GET["page_number"], 1);
```

Easy to use in the future as well.

Comment: +1 good advice on better way to approach this, however I would also point out to OP that filter_var or filter_input might be a more concise way o validate input such as this. I would also consider casting the input to integer to be consistent across both cases.

Comment: just for the record . `page?page_number=%2B5` and `page?page_number=-5` will pass your function .,  `page?page_number=0x5` will pass too if you are before php 7.0.0 . although  a **string** variable equals "+5" or "-5" will be evaluated as integer in a  mathematical context in loosely typed language like php . but this is might not be your intended behavior of the function.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to try the shorthand of that equation, you can go for 

`$pageNumber = isset($_GET['page_number']) && intval($_GET['page_number']) > 0 ? $_GET['page_number'] : 1`

This will check, if the page_number is set or not. If set then is the value greater than 0 then get the page number, otherwise set to 1.